# Stop browsers from auto paste highlighted text into the find bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

You highlight a text on a webpage, press ctrl+F and then chrome and Firefox auto paste it into the find bar

I'm not that lazy to be excited about such a feature that can be done in two easy steps. Why I don't like it? It removes the previous string in the find bar without a way to restore it, at least I tried ctrl+z (edit: it works for Firefox only)

I recall Firefox started it so I stopped using it and went to chrome, and now it was introduced recently to chrome as well so I really want to turn this off for both these browsers

my os is Windows 10 64 bit. Chrome is up to date v. 81.0.4044.122 official build 64 bit. Firefox, which ctrl+z works, is up to date 75.0 64 bit

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem, but Ctrl+Z does work in my installations of Chrome 81.0.4044.122 and Firefox 75.0.0.7398 on Windows 10 in that specific situation. Pressing Ctrl+Z restores the previous search string.

Comment: @Jesper true for Firefox, but not for chrome. I guess I should switch back to Firefox although it's not that convenient to press ctrl+z every time. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome, and well, it's actually true for both.  Note that I specifically said that in my installations of the given versions, it works. But I trust when you say it doesn't work in your specific installation of Chrome on your specific operating system. Did you try updating Chrome to the same version? And are you using Windows 10? The behaviour might be different in different operating systems. Perhaps you could state the operating system in the question so you can get more specific responses.

Comment: @Jesper ^Z doesn't work for me in the same version of Chrome... in fact it appears to hop over the previous entry - ^F type `123`, close find, ^F type `456`, close find, select text, ^F, ^Z, I see `123` (not `456`)

Comment: @Jesper it's been a while since I asked here :) my os is Windows 10 64 bit. Chrome is up to date v. 81.0.4044.122 official build 64 bit. Firefox, which ctrl+z works, is up to date 75.0 64 bit

Comment: @Attie it's random. Sometimes it reverses the auto pasted text, sometimes it does not. It depends also whether you did found it on the page or not. Anyway, ctrl+z is definitely not the trusty solution

Comment: @attie Attie and Sanny: I see the problem now after Attie's very precise steps. That looks like a bug to me. When I switched to another tab and pressed F3 (another shortcut for Find) to test it, suddenly 456 showed up in the Ctrl+Z sequence, which it didn't in this tab. Seems quite random, yes.